# Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.2:prepare failed. NullPointerException

Tags: maven, jenkins, release

Here is the Context:
I have successfully built the project with the following commands (called from maven-release-plugin in Jenkins)

```
mvn clean -Pall
mvn generate-sources -Pgs 
mvn -PjenkinsBuild install package assembly:single -Pall -Denvironment=dev
```

Now, when I try to release the project with maven-release-plugin in Jenkins, with the following commands. It failed.(error log and pom at the end)

```
mvn -X release:prepare release:perform
```

Tried some unsuccessful solutions:
1.Modified the config of maven-release-plugin, suspecting developers and Jenkins are using different vesion of SVN.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <branchBase>${svn.base}/branches/releases</branchBase>
    <tagBase>${svn.base}/tags/releases/</tagBase>
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    <suppressCommitBeforeBranch>true</suppressCommitBeforeBranch>
    <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
    <updateBranchVersions>true</updateBranchVersions>
    <updateWorkingCopyVersions>false</updateWorkingCopyVersions>
    <providerImplementations>
          <svn>javasvn</svn>
    </providerImplementations>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

2. Tried to added the groupID explicitly, according to one of the suggestions

   tc.strongview
   strongview-soap-client
   jar
   Strongview SOAP Client

And a section of the POM

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>tc.strongview</groupId>
<artifactId>strongview-etl-core</artifactId>
<version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

    <scm>
    <connection>
        scm:svn:https://xxxxxxxxx/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2
    </connection>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:svn:https://xxxxxxxxx/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2
    </developerConnection>
    <url>https://xxxxxxxxx/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2
    </url>
    </scm>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>strongview-etl-common</module>
    <module>strongview-soap-client</module>
    <module>strongview-etl-definitions</module>
</modules>

<distributionManagement>
...................................................
...................................................
...................................................
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
...................................................
...................................................
...................................................
</repositories>

<profiles>
...................................................
...................................................
...................................................
</profile>

</profiles>

<properties>
...................................................
...................................................
...................................................
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.github.shyiko.servers-maven-extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>servers-maven-extension</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <branchBase>${svn.base}/branches/releases</branchBase>
                <tagBase>${svn.base}/tags/releases/</tagBase>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <suppressCommitBeforeBranch>true</suppressCommitBeforeBranch>
                <remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>
                <updateBranchVersions>true</updateBranchVersions>
                <updateWorkingCopyVersions>false</updateWorkingCopyVersions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${project.parent.basedir}/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <finalName>${distribution.name}</finalName>
                <includeProjectBuildFilters>true</includeProjectBuildFilters>
                <ignoreMissingDescriptor>true</ignoreMissingDescriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>${deployment.server}</serverId>
                <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
                <includes>${distribution.name}.zip</includes>
                <url>scp://${etl.server.url}:${etl.server.distribution.dir}</url>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
...................................................
...................................................
...................................................
</dependencies>
```

New error log released with Maven 3.3.3 and maven-release-plugin 2.5.2 and simple "release:prepare release:perform"

```
Started by user 
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven
Cleaning up /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/.
Deleting /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/pom.xml.releaseBackup
Deleting /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/release.properties
Deleting /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/pom.xml
Deleting /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/strongview-etl-common/pom.xml.releaseBackup
Deleting /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/strongview-soap-client/pom.xml.releaseBackup
Deleting /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/strongview-etl-definitions/pom.xml.releaseBackup
Updating https://xxxxxxxxx/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2 at revision '2015-08-04T15:33:30.474 -0400'
At revision 80
no change for https://xxxxxxxxx/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2 since the previous build
Parsing POMs
[strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven] $ /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -cp /data/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.4.jar:/data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/3.3.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/3.3.3 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.36.jar /data/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.4.jar /data/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.4.jar 35483
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=0.2.1-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=0.2.0 -X -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T07:57:37-04:00)
Maven home: /data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /data/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/3.3.3/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] strongview-etl-core
[INFO] Strongview SOAP Client
[INFO] strongview-etl-common
[INFO] strongview-etl-definitions
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building strongview-etl-core 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) @ strongview-etl-core ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.tag, **/pom.xml.branch, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.backup
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd "/data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven" && svn --non-interactive status
[INFO] Working directory: /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven
[DEBUG] ?       release.properties
[DEBUG] Ignoring changed file: release.properties
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] Transforming 'strongview-etl-core'...
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO] Transforming 'Strongview SOAP Client'...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] strongview-etl-core ................................ FAILURE [  2.944 s]
[INFO] Strongview SOAP Client ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] strongview-etl-common .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] strongview-etl-definitions ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.724 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-04T15:33:41-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/139M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project strongview-etl-core: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project strongview-etl-core: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.translateUrlPath(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:847)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RewritePomsForReleasePhase.translateScm(RewritePomsForReleasePhase.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RewritePomsForReleasePhase.transformScm(RewritePomsForReleasePhase.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transformDocument(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transformProject(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.transform(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRewritePomsPhase.execute(AbstractRewritePomsPhase.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/strongview-etl-definitions/pom.xml to tc.strongview/strongview-etl-definitions/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/strongview-etl-definitions-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/strongview-soap-client/pom.xml to tc.strongview/strongview-soap-client/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/strongview-soap-client-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/strongview-etl-common/pom.xml to tc.strongview/strongview-etl-common/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/strongview-etl-common-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release4 - Latest Maven/pom.xml to tc.strongview/strongview-etl-core/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/strongview-etl-core-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: From the error log, it failed while trying to rewrite the POM:   at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RewritePomsForReleasePhase.translateUrlPath(RewritePomsForReleasePhase.java:271). I am trying to find out which NULL path that caused the failure

Answer (score 1):

For me its resolved scm tag and release plugin moved to child pom. It means deleted scm  tag and release plugin details from the parent pom

Comment: Had the same translateUrlPath issue, solution for me, was that the scm was only mentioned in parent pom, so I added it to all child modules with their respective scm urls and it worked

Answer (score 0):

First what comes into my mind. Why are you using an ancient version of the maven-release-plugin 2.2.2 which is from 2011 ? Not an more uptodate version?

Why are you using an very buggy version of Maven 3.0.3 ? Not at least the final one of the 3.0.X release line (3.0.5) ?

Furthermore you are calling maven like this:

```
mvn clean -Pall
mvn generate-sources -Pgs 
mvn -PjenkinsBuild install package assembly:single -Pall -Denvironment=dev
```

That shows that you didn't understand Maven's life cycle.

If you call `mvn package` will run all [life cycle phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) including `install` which means calling:

```
mvn install package
```

does not make sense.
Furthermore you are calling `mvn ...assembly:single` which does not make sense either. You should bind the execution of maven-assembly-plugin to the life-cycle. An other point you have configured in the pom file:

${project.parent.basedir}/assembly/distribution.xml

You should never leave the location of your current module by using a configuration like this, this will cause trouble.

A realy Maven build should always be callable by using the simple one like this:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

If you like to make a release it should work like this:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

If this does not work i'm not astonished you get trouble using your CI server.

Also you are violating the best practices in SVN...using tags/trunk/branches concept.

In the log i can see the following:

```
Building on master in workspace /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release
Cleaning local Directory .
Checking out https://xxxxxxxx/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2 at revision '2015-08-04T10:08:20.758 -0400'
.....................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................
AU        pom.xml
 U        .
At revision 77
no change for https://svn.transcontinental.ca/svn/strongview-etl-core/branches/releases/strongview-etl-core-0.2 since the previous build
[strongview-etl-core-Release] $ /bin/sh -xe /data/jenkins/tmp/hudson5945883868250298288.sh
+ cd /data/jenkins/workspace/strongview-etl-core-Release/
```

Which shows me that you are already on a tag which can't work, cause to do a release you should be either on a branch or trunk which contains the `-SNAPSHOT` version in your pom file...which does not look like it..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I heeded your advices. I redid the release with latest maven-release-plugin 2.5.2 and both Maven 3.0.5 and 3.3.3. I also use the simple "-X release:prepare release:perform". (However, I keep the same SVN structure branches/releases & tags/releases .vs. branches/features & tags/features. We have 20 different Maven projects setup with this structure and they release properly to Nexus)  So back to this new project with updated Maven and plugin, I still got the same error (new error log is posted above) . Thank you again for your insights/advices

Comment: A NPE is a strong indication that there could be a bug in the maven code.

Comment: <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <scm>
   <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.xxxxxxxxxx.ca/svn/dpm_publishing/branches/releases/1.0</connection>
   <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.xxxxxxx.ca/svn/dpm_publishing/branches/releases/1.0</developerConnection>
      <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/Packaging</url>
    </scm>

Comment: <version>1.0.3</version>
    <scm>
   <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ca/svn/dpm_publishing/tags/releases/Packaging-1.0.3</connection>
   <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ca/svn/dpm_publishing/tags/releases/Packaging-1.0.3</developerConnection>
      <url>scm:svn:https://svn.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ca/svn/dpm_publishing/tags/releases/Packaging-1.0.3</url>
    </scm>

Comment: It works properly for 20 other projs, just to show that the SVN structure probably not the cause of this problem (khmarbaise please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you)